# Spring Boot app keeps crashing on startup even with spring-boot-starter-web dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy my spring boot application to kubernetes on GCP. I created a docker image and tried to do a helm chart release of the same. The docker image runs perfectly fine when I run using `docker-compose` however it crashes when deploying in cluster on gke.

Here is my `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.1")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage', version: '1.2.7.RELEASE'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.8.0'
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/yeV24QxB) is the logs I get.

Logs don't give any info even on TRACE mode. Another thing is that most search results yielded to include `starter-web` but I already have it included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the app itself contains no error or any other suspicious items in log. You also said that your docker container is working in local which means there is no issue with the container as is. Did you check the kubernetes events using something similar to `kubectl get events --sort-by=.metadata.creationTimestamp`?? This might give more info on the issue.

Comment: thanks for this hint. I did check the events, it seems that health check endpoint was not correct. The answer helped me find that